# Best datatype to store a single digit?

Tags: mysql, types

I need a datatype to store this range: `[0 - 9]`. Something like this:

```
+-----+
| col |
+-----+
| 3   |
| 2   |
| 8   |
| 0   |
| 2   |
| 1   |
+-----+
```

What datatype is the best in this case?

Comment: @Mihai `Tinyit(1) UNSIGNED` stores `[0 - 255]`. But I need to just one single digit.

Comment: What use will that column have?

Comment: @Alejandro There is 9 parts, that column keeps the number of one of those parts.

Comment: Why do you need to enforce single digit by a type, and not a check constraint, if you really need this?

Comment: @ConsiderMe Yes I can do that using a check constraint too! But I thought implementing that using a datatype could be more simpler *(and maybe more optimize)*

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the use case for `ENUM`s, right there.

Comment: Turned out to be a surprisingly good question worthy of archiving ... though you should better define your requirements than asking for the "best". Best per what metrics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the documentation, I'm not clear on whether the size of a `DECIMAL(1,0)` is "rounded up" to four bytesm or whether the single digit counts as a "left-over digit", resulting in a width of a single byte for the whole data type.

Regardless, you can't use less space than a `TINYINT`, because [a `TINYINT` is a single byte wide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html), and a byte is the smallest unit of data on a computer (without getting into bitpacking, which doesn't seem plausible on tabular data!).

**So, of the numeric types, use a `TINYINT`. Anything else is needless obfuscation.**

That being said, I'm a big fan of `ENUM`s, and this would seem to be a perfect case for them. [Since your enumeration would have fewer than 255 possible values, like a `TINYINT` it would only take a single byte.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html)

```
ENUM('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
```

Sadly, it's a little verbose to write out. But at least now your values are inherently range-constrained.

Comment: Seems reasonable ...! Well maybe I go with `TINYINT(1)`, Anyway ok thanks, +1

Comment: Per documentation `DECIMAL(1,0)` would also fit into 1 byte, but I still think `TINYINT` is the way to go.

Comment: @ConsiderMe: Where does the documentation say that? I can't find it. See my comment on Harper's answer.

Comment: The storage requirements for the integer and fractional parts of each value are determined separately. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: @ConsiderMe: People keep linking that page but nobody seems willing to quote me the passage on it that actually backs up their claims.

Comment: "For example, a DECIMAL(18,9) column has nine digits on either side of the decimal point, so the integer part and the fractional part each require 4 bytes. A DECIMAL(20,6) column has fourteen integer digits and six fractional digits. The integer digits require four bytes for nine of the digits and 3 bytes for the remaining five digits. The six fractional digits require 3 bytes."

Comment: @ConsiderMe: Precisely none of that quote says anything about `DECIMAL(1,0)` requiring only one byte of storage. It's not even alluded to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure, but it shows an approach which should be taken into consideration while calculating the actual storage usage.

Comment: @ConsiderMe: I don't see how that validates your assertion, sorry. In fact I'm growingly convinced that the passage [_"Each multiple of nine digits requires four bytes, and the 'leftover' digits require some fraction of four bytes. The storage required for excess digits is given by the following table."_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) means a `DECIMAL(1,0)` will take four bytes, which is four times what's needed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand your doubt, though I guess we should look at the table and presume from that example. Neither it says that DECIMAL(5,0) is also different from DECIMAL(15,4) explicitly, but this is what the table is for.

Comment: Bah, now I'm thinking the single digit is a "leftover" digit!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree it's confusing. To me the part _"The storage requirements for the integer and fractional parts of each value are determined separately."_ speaks the most. I guess we should just leave it as it is for now :)

Comment: Please stop talking about this useless topic ..! I used `TINYINT(1)` and everything has been done.

Comment: @ConsiderMe: Yeah. To be honest, for me the fact that we've even had to have this discussion in the first place, while `TINYINT` cannot possibly be worse, means using `DECIMAL(1,0)` is unnecessarily unclear and confusing by comparison. :)

Comment: @Shafizadeh: We want to expand our knowledge and understanding. So should you.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Wait, why did you ask for free help in finding the best datatype, then ignore my suggestion to use `ENUM`, which does _everything_ you want?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP just wanted the problem solved, it's been solved for him I guess. Anyway, I'm leaving a +1 mark, since I agree with this answer. And I didn't find this conversation useless.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because I saw your new update right now..! You told me use `TINYINT` in the first version.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: That was twenty minutes ago, and only two or three minutes after the first revision was posted!

Comment: Well yeah .. I read it, `ENUM` could be the best answer in my case.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: I think it is :)

Comment: Honestly marking your solution as my answer is somehow hard for me...! I don't know why, Maybe because you are a female and I have a bad feeling about it. But in fact your answer is the best, So I have to accept it as my answer :-(

Comment: @Shafizadeh: You're finding it "hard" and sad to accept the answer that helped you the most ... because it was [allegedly] written by a woman? Is that right?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I don't know why I cannot accept a women can be better than me in some cases.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Well, I suppose it's better that you find it out now, than later. Congratulations. :)

Comment: Hah ..! And this ^ comment makes me sad either `:-)`, Well good night `;-)`

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Sweet dreams.

Answer (score 2):

You can force it to store a single digit using `DECIMAL(1,0)`.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: I dunno. That article is surprisingly light on detail regarding smaller values for `M`. The fact that it "packs nine digits into four bytes" suggests to be an underlying representation based on shifting into 32-bit integers, which suggests the minimum storage width of the type is still 32 bits. Thus, this would save no space at all over an `INT`, and take _four times more_ than a `TINYINT`. But this is just my speculation.

Comment: "Storing a single digit" confuses storage and representation. However, I now agree that this probably only requires a single byte. I still don't recommend it as the solution.

Comment: I personally always use TINYINT(1), but the OP wanted to force it to be one digit, which DECIMAL(1,0) does.  Also, some opinionated frameworks (ahem, Rails/ActiveRecord) tend to treat TINYINT(1) as a boolean.

Answer (score -1):

You can use int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint depends on the requirement.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

May be you can store the values in enumeration and use the same class.

@Shafizadeh I'm new here and I've mention to use enum first among all the answers but my answer got marked negative sadly.

Comment: You may want to link to the _MySQL_ documentation instead.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are not the same thing.